# Is it possible to add tooltip (mouse over listener) to google heat map data?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I've developed an HTML/Javascript page that uses google API to display a map.  I have a list of coordinates that I draw on the map using google heat map.  My problem is that I want to add a tool-tip so that when end user mouses over a section of coordinates on the heatmap, it pops up and displays the total number of coordinates in that section.  The heatmap data is not always connected. For example, there could be a cluster/blob of 2 coordinates on one side of town & a separate cluster of 500 coordinates on other side of town.

Relevant Code:

```
function createHeatMap(coordinates) {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: { lat: 33.xxxxxx, lng: -84.xxxxxx },
                zoom: 13.4,
                maxZoom: 15,
            });

            var heatmapData = [];

            coordinates.forEach(function (coord) {
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coord.latitude, coord.longitude);
                heatmapData.push(latLng);
            });

            heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                data: heatmapData,
                map: map,
            });
            const gradient = [
                "rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)",
                "rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)",
                "rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)",
                "rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)",
                "rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)",
                "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)",
            ];

            heatmap.set('radius', 20);
            heatmap.set('gradient', gradient);
            heatmap.set('maxIntensity', 2);
            heatmap.set("opacity", 0.35);

            //Add mouse over listener to display # of coordinates 
        }
```

I've tried adding an event listener for 'mouseover' to simply display the total number of coordinates (not broken out by cluster), but nothing happens when I mouse over.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(heatmap, 'mouseover', function (event) {
                var totalCoordinates = heatmapData.length;
                var content = 'Total Coordinates: ' + totalCoordinates;

                infoWindow.setContent(content);
                infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
                infoWindow.open(map);
             });

            google.maps.event.addListener(heatmap, 'mouseout', function () {
                infoWindow.close();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution for this either... However, I made a workaround by doing this:

```
map.addListener("mousemove", (e: google.maps.MapMouseEvent) => {
  const rdLng = (n?: number) => Math.round(n || 0);
  const lat = rdLng(e.latLng?.lat());
  const lng = rdLng(e.latLng?.lng());

  // data is the heatmap data
  const location = data.find(
    (h) =>
      rdLng(h.location.lat()) === lat && rdLng(h.location.lng()) === lng
  );

  if (location) {
    setVisibleInfo(location);
  }
});
```

Hopefully, this can help you out a little